# Using zabbix_sender for host discovery

Tags: zabbix, autodiscovery

I'm writing an application which delivers data from remote devices over an HTTP API. These devices are on a mobile data connection and have limited resources.

I wish to receive custom monitoring data over the HTTP API, relying on the security model designed in the application, and push that data to Zabbix directly (or indirectly) from node.js. I do not wish to use Zabbix Agent on the remote devices.

I see that I can use zabbix_sender to send data to a Zabbix server containing a pre-configured host. This works great. I intend to deliver monitoring data over my custom API, and when received give this data to zabbix_sender inside the server network.

The problem is there are many devices in the field and more are being added all the time.

## TL;DR:

When zabbix_sender provides a custom hostname which doesn't exist in Zabbix already, it fails.

I would like to auto-add discovered hosts, based upon new hostnames from zabbix_sender. How would I do this?

Also, extra respect if anyone can give examples of how to avoid zabbix_sender and send data directly from node.js to the Zabbix server. I mean: suggest an NPM package that you have experience using. (Update: Found working node.js package here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-zabbix-sender)

Zabbix configuration: I'm learning from Zabbix 2.4 installed in Docker, no custom configuration from this Dockerhub: https://hub.docker.com/r/zabbix/zabbix-2.4/

Answer (score 4):

1. Probably the best would be to use the Zabbix API to [create hosts](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/api/reference/host/create) directly.
2. Alternatively, you could set up an action and emulate active agent connection, which would make Zabbix create the host via the [active agent auto-regstration](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/discovery/auto_registration).
3. You could also use [low level discovery](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/discovery/low_level_discovery) (LLD) to send in JSON, which would result in hosts/items being created, based on prototypes.

In all of these cases you have to wait for one minute (by default) for the hosts to appear in the Zabbix cache, then you can send the data.

Also note that Zabbix 2.4 is not supported anymore, it will receive no fixes - it is not a "long-term support" release.